# UTF-8でCSVを作成したいが、ANSIで出力されてしまう。

Tags: php, cakephp

PHP5.4(Cakephp2の環境)で文字コードのUTF-8でCSVを作成したいのですが、メモ帳で出力した文字コードを見てみるとANSIになってしまっている形です。どう修正すれば実現できるでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<?php
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
    public function main()
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8');
        $array = array(mb_convert_encoding("Windows", "UTF-8"),
            mb_convert_encoding("Mac", "UTF-8"),
            mb_convert_encoding("Linux", "UTF-8")
        );

        $file = fopen("test.csv", "w");
        if($file){
            var_dump(fputcsv($file, $array));
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: ご指摘していただいたとおり、fwrite($file, '\xEF\xBB\xBF');の記載を加えてみたのですが出力したCSVのファイルをメモ帳で開くとその中身の先頭に「\xEF\xBB\xBF」が新しく追記されただけで文字コードはANSIのままでした。やり方が間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答の`fwrite($file, '\xEF\xBB\xBF');`は`fwrite($file, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");`の間違いですね。(シングルクォートでなく、ダブルクォートを使用。)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。メモ帳でUTF8として出力されていることが確認できました。あと、複数の行をCSVに出力し、サクラエディタで中身を見てみると2行目から行の頭に空白が存在します。UTF8でCSV出力し、サクラエディタで空白なく見れるようにするのはどう修正すればよろしいでしょうか。ご存知でしたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの先頭にUTF-8を示すBOMがWriteされていないからでしょう。
[PHP エクセルで文字化けさせないCSVの作り方](http://dev.blog.fairway.ne.jp/php%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84csv%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E6%96%B9/)
以下のようにCSVデータ書き込みの前に追加しておけば良いのでは？

```
        if($file){
            fwrite($file, '\xEF\xBB\xBF');
            var_dump(fputcsv($file, $array));
        }
```

---

**注)**
コメントされたように、出力されたCSVファイルを取り扱うソフトによっては、かえってBOMがあると誤動作をする場合があるので、対象ソフトの仕様を確認してからの方が良いでしょう。

ちなみに近々行われるWindows10 19H1アップデートで、メモ帳も色々改善されるようです。
[「メモ帳」に多数の改善、BOMなしUTF-8がデフォルト保存形式に ～「Windows 10 19H1」](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1157696.html)

Comment: エクセル(やWindows上のツールやアプリ)に読み込ませるのが目的ならこれで良いでしょうが、他環境のツール等に読み込ませることが目的の場合、このやり方ではファイルの先頭に余分な1文字が存在することになり、誤動作する場合があります。

Comment: @OOPerさん、ご指摘の通りです。でも"UTF-8 BOM"で検索すれば、直ぐにいっぱい例があると判ることですね。今やってみると [UTF-8のBOMにはまった話](https://qiita.com/MuriNishimori/items/a89fe986e28909208e30) とかが上位に出てきます。

Comment: 質問者はメモ帳を使っているのだから、これで良いとは思うんですが、UTF-8にBOMを付与することに関する注意点は回答中に含めた方が良いでしょう。リンク先にあるとか検索すれば出てくるでは、このサイトの趣旨に則った良い回答とは言えません。

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず、php上で “Windows” や “Mac” が、どういうバイト値からどういうバイト値に変わったか、確認してみればどうですか。
その後、UTF-8 について調べればいいと思います。
知識が足りていないと思います。